# How to create geometry column from nested lists

Tags: geopandas, shapely, pandas

How can I create mixed geometries types from nested lists ?

```
from pandas import DataFrame

row1 = [
         [
           [
             [-73.932204, 45.491553], [-73.931682, 45.491085], 
             [-73.93198, 45.490987], [-73.932312, 45.490895], 
             [-73.932718, 45.49127], [-73.932962, 45.491495], 
             [-73.93301, 45.49154], [-73.933186, 45.491695]
           ]
         ],
         [
           [
             [-73.932977, 45.492432], [-73.933873, 45.493231], 
             [-73.933467, 45.493287], [-73.933426, 45.493302], 
             [-73.933399, 45.493352], [-73.933294, 45.493371], 
             [-73.933274, 45.493396], [-73.933246, 45.493455]
           ]
         ]
       ]

row2 = [
         [
           [-73.487496, 45.696142], [-73.48745, 45.696304], 
           [-73.487949, 45.696373], [-73.487995, 45.696211], 
           [-73.487496, 45.696142]
         ]
       ]

data = {"coordinates": [row1, row2], "type": ["MultiPolygon", "Polygon"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

Comment: Are all coordinates like these: (multiple nested list `[[[ [x,y],[x,y], ...]], [[ [x,y], [x,y], ...]]]`)  or (one nested list) `[[[ [x,y], [x,y], ... ]]]`)?

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz, Polygon: [[ [X, Y], [X, Y], [X, Y], .... ]] MultiPlygon: [[[ [X, Y], [X, Y], [X, Y]]], [[[X, Y], [X., Y], [X, Y] ]], .....]

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz, Sorry I did a extra brackets in row2, I updated row2 in my question. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can review and use this script:

```
from geopandas import GeoDataFrame
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, MultiPolygon

row1 = [
         [
           [
             [-73.932204, 45.491553], [-73.931682, 45.491085],
             [-73.93198, 45.490987], [-73.932312, 45.490895],
             [-73.932718, 45.49127], [-73.932962, 45.491495],
             [-73.93301, 45.49154], [-73.933186, 45.491695]
           ]
         ],
         [
           [
             [-73.932977, 45.492432], [-73.933873, 45.493231],
             [-73.933467, 45.493287], [-73.933426, 45.493302],
             [-73.933399, 45.493352], [-73.933294, 45.493371],
             [-73.933274, 45.493396], [-73.933246, 45.493455]
           ]
         ]
       ]

row2 = [       
          [
            [-73.487496, 45.696142], [-73.48745, 45.696304],
            [-73.487949, 45.696373], [-73.487995, 45.696211],
            [-73.487496, 45.696142]
          ]        
       ]

rows = [row1, row2]

data = {"geometry": [], "type": []}
for row in rows:
    if len(row) == 1:
        g = Polygon(row[0])
        data["geometry"].append(g)
        data["type"].append("Polygon")
    else:
        g = MultiPolygon([Polygon(r[0]) for r in row])
        data["geometry"].append(g)
        data["type"].append("MultiPolygon")

gdf = GeoDataFrame(data)
print(gdf)

# OUT:
#                                             geometry          type
# 0  MULTIPOLYGON (((-73.93220 45.49155, -73.93168 ...  MultiPolygon
# 1  POLYGON ((-73.48750 45.69614, -73.48745 45.696...       Polygon
```